# Laravel 5.2 - access authenticated user in route binding

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is it possible to access the authenticated user in a route binding.

```
Route::bind('account', function($account_id)
{
    dd(auth()->user()); // it's null :(

    $account = App\Models\Account::where('business_id', auth()->user()->business_id)
        ->where('account_id', $account_id)
        ->first()

    return !is_null($account) ? $account : App::abort(404);
});
```

I've tried grouping the route binding within some auth middleware, no dice - is this a thing? It would be really useful to pull off, to avoid extra validation in the controller.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the bind is inside the `Auth` middleware you should be able to access it using `Auth::user()`

```
Route::bind('account', function($account_id)
{
    dd(Auth::user()); // Here is the change

    $account = App\Models\Account::where('business_id', Auth::user()->business_id)
        ->where('account_id', $account_id)
        ->first()

    return !is_null($account) ? $account : App::abort(404);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Auth`. This works for me:

RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(Router $router) {

    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('account', function () {
        dd(\Auth::user());
    });
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('account/{account}', function () {
    //test
});
```

prints user object

Comment: My bad didn't realise you were utilising the RouteServiceProvider. So I'm going to have to bind the authenticated user within the boot method.

Comment: I need scope of the auth object in a bind in my routes file.